Self-deleting, then self-undeleting, a Staging Ground post 24 hours later allows it to be auto-published without review
I voted to close a Staging Ground question as off-topic. The asker then self-deleted the post about ten minutes after my close vote and comment. All good, right? Well, no, they self-undeleted it 41 hours later. What appears to have happened then is the Staging Ground noticed the post was "over 24 hours old" without any responses (I think it was still in a 'new' status technically?), and auto-published it twenty minutes after undeletion! The post spent a grand total of 43 minutes in Staging Ground in an undeleted state before being published, without ever getting any review other than my close vote.
This is obviously a bug/exploit (not that I necessarily think this asker intentionally did this to skip Staging Ground), wherein users can post a question to Staging Ground, self-delete, wait 24 hours, undelete, and have Staging Ground kick their question out onto the main site immediately.
I see two ways to deal with this exploit:

Pause and unpause the clock/counter for auto-publication whenever a question is deleted and then undeleted.

This counter should also be reset to zero anytime the asker makes an edit or requests re-review (the 24-hour window is ostensibly "24 hours without response from any reviewer", hopefully).

When there are major changes or close vote reviews on a post, it should probably pause the counter as well indefinitely, until another action is made (until a re-review request, essentially); when the only reviewer response is "this is bad", we shouldn't be auto-publishing that post just because no one else sees it for 24 hours.



Remove the ability to self-undelete Staging Ground posts. There's no reason to delete a post in the Staging Ground if you still ultimately want it to be published... a post with problems should be edited, instead. A better workflow/UX would be to show a confirmation warning upon self-deletion of "if you self-delete, you won't be able to undelete this post later; you'll have to ask a new question instead" or similar, and then enforce that.



And for what it's worth, I also don't think users should be able to self-delete/undelete a single post more than once, total, but that's not really a Staging Ground issue. What is the legitimate reason for this user deleting their post 3 times and undeleting it twice? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78582909/timeline Beats me...

Note: close votes do reset the clock. Major changes blocks it indefinitely until the post either goes to another state like Re-evaluate or minor edits. I don't remember if edits reset the clock or not.

@TylerH the usual reason, not understanding how to use Stack Overflow correctly. Given the context is the staging ground... that is kind of to be expected isn't it?

@Gimby Well, maybe, but they undeleted it and deleted it on Main, too, after it was graduated. And if that's the only reason (not understanding), then stands to reason it doesn't need to be a feature, IMO.

@TylerH No, but IMO it would imply the staging ground failed them because no knowledge of what not to do was gained :)

I mean, expected, or user error aside, one shouldn't be able to post to SG, delete the post, then undelete it 2 days later for it to be published shortly after.


Have a deletion timer instead of an auto-publication timer. Set it to, say, 9 days, to match "abandoned closed" questions.


IIRC the auto-publication after 24h only applies to New questions, not to any questions in Re-Evaluate.

Side note: Judging from this timeline or that one where I requested major changes after 24h were over, it doesn't seem like auto publishing happens at exactly 24h.

@KarlKnechtel We already have Roomba in the SG and I think it's considered a bug. Also, not publishing new questions automatically would be an issue with questions not being posted if nobody is interested in them (which is typically not acceptable but may have happened to some questions in Re-evaluate during the strike).
